# Laravel 5 defining old input on select

Tags: php, select, laravel-5

in my controller, I am passing a list of clients to the view

```
public function edit(Project $project)
{
    $clients = Client::select('clientName', 'id')->get();

    return View::make('projects.edit', compact('project', 'clients'));
}
```

Now in my view, I am currently doing this

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('clientName', 'Client Name:', array('class' => 'col-sm-5 control-label blue')) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <select class="clientName" name="clientName">
            @foreach($clients as $client)
                @if (Input::old('clients') == $client->id)
                <option value="{{ $client->id }}" selected="selected">{{ $client->clientName }}</option>
                @else
                <option value="{{ $client->id }}">{{ $client->clientName }}</option>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is have the default select option set as the old input.  At the moment, the select displays with all the clients, but the old value is not default.

How would I go about making it the default option?

Thanks

**Update**
I do a alternative way I am trying.  In my edit function I do

```
public function edit(Project $project)
{
    $clients = Client::lists('clientName', 'id');

    return View::make('projects.edit', compact('project', 'clients'));
}
```

And then in my view I do

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('clientName', 'Client Name:', array('class' => 'col-sm-5 control-label blue')) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        {!! Form::select('clientName', $clients, Input::old('clients'), ['class' => 'clientName']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

Seem to have the same issue though, the client is not the old client as the default selected option.

Thanks

Comment: humn... if you allow me to ask, what are you trying to edit? the old('clients') that you are using refers to what?
Are you aware of the Form::model method? There are easier ways to get what you want done. Lets see if I can help you. Btw, you can use `Client::lists('clientName','id')` instead of `Client::select('clientName', 'id')->get()`, can't you?

Comment: I have updated the original post, which uses the list option instead

Comment: I didn't understand well what is your new problem, can you explain a little better?

Comment: Sure, no problem.  I have updated the original post again.  Thanks

Comment: Can you check what is being returned to your `Input::old('clients')`? 
Put a `{{ var_dump(Input::old('clients')) }}` somewhere in your view, then try again using `Input::old('clientName')` because your select is named that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select name is `clientName` but your old input is looking to a field with the name `clients`.

The following should work:

```
<option value="{{ $client->id }}" {!! old('clientName', $project->client->id) == $client->id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' !!}>{{ $client->clientName }}</option>
```

Comment: Hi there, i've been battling with this issue too, but the only thing i changed here was by adding !! as you suggested and now it works. What does the !! do?

Comment: It can be that you were trying to echo partial raw html, and in that case `{!! !!}` is the proper Blade tag to escape and output such kind of content.